# Class decorator signature with required method

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to define a decorator signature for class decorator in typescript for a javascript code that already exists. Let's say I have some already defined class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
  someMethod() {
  }
}
```

Then there is also some class decorator method which take input class but it requires that the input class has some other method defined before it is decorated.

```
function decorate(someClass) {
  // some properties and methods injection happens here
}
```

Then in my typescript code I would create a class to decorate as:

```
class Bar extends Foo {
  requiredMethod(): any {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then for definitions I tried:

```
interface WithRequiredMethod {
  requiredMethod(): any;
}

declare function decorate<C extends Foo>(input: C & WithRequiredMethod): C;
```

And then call it as:

```
const DocoratedBar = decorate(Bar);
```

Unfortunately typescript doesn't recognise Bar as valid input even if it has `requiredMethod` defined. Is there any way to define `decorate` signature to validate presence of `requiredMethod` on input class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it. But you need to write this

```
interface WithRequiredMethod {
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-any
  requiredMethod(): any;
}

declare function decorate<C extends new () => Foo & WithRequiredMethod>(target: C): C;
```

The reason is that the decorator targets a class. A class is really just a constructor function. So the object that gets decorated is actually a constructor function for objects of type `Foo & WithRequiredMethod`.

For example, if we only wanted to restrict our decorator to targeting `Foo` or one of its subclasses we would write

```
declare function decorate<T extends typeof Foo>(target: T): T;
```

Interestingly, the error originally received is stating that `class Bar` does not implement `WithRequiredMethod`, which is indeed true, but not what we wanted to say. But, it could well be useful to say and when so we can leverage decorators to enforce both static and instance properties.

Consider:

```
declare function decorate<
  C extends WithRequiredMethod & (new () => Foo & WithRequiredMethod)
>(target: C): C;
```

Now we apply this to `class Bar` and again receive the error that `requiredMethod` is missing. We can however satisfy the requirement by adding a static`requiredMethod` method to `Bar`:

```
@decorate class Bar extends Foo {
  // required by `decorate`
  static requiredMethod() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-null-keyword
    return null;
  }

  // also required by `decorate`
  requiredMethod() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-null-keyword
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I overlooked.